# Different read and write count using cachegrind and callgrind

Tags: c, assembly, callgrind, cachegrind, gem5

I am doing some experiments with Cachegrind, Callgrind and Gem5. I noticed that a number of accesses were counted as read for cachegrind, as write for callgrind and for both read and write by gem5.

Let's take a very simple example:

```
int main() {
    int i, l;

    for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        l++;
        l++;
        l++;
        l++;
        l++;
        l++;
        l++;
        l++;
        l++;
        l++;
        ... (100 times)
     }
 }
```

I compile with:

> gcc ex.c --static -o ex

So basically, according to the asm file, `addl  $1, -8(%rbp)` is executed 100,000 times. Since it's both a read and a write, I was expecting 100k read and 100k write. However, cachegrind only counts them as read and callgrind only as write.

```
 % valgrind --tool=cachegrind --I1=512,8,64 --D1=512,8,64
--L2=16384,8,64 ./ex
==15356== Cachegrind, a cache and branch-prediction profiler
==15356== Copyright (C) 2002-2012, and GNU GPL'd, by Nicholas Nethercote et al.
==15356== Using Valgrind-3.8.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==15356== Command: ./ex
==15356== 
--15356-- warning: L3 cache found, using its data for the LL simulation.
==15356== 
==15356== I   refs:      111,535
==15356== I1  misses:        475
==15356== LLi misses:        280
==15356== I1  miss rate:    0.42%
==15356== LLi miss rate:    0.25%
==15356== 
==15356== D   refs:      104,894  (103,791 rd   + 1,103 wr)
==15356== D1  misses:        557  (    414 rd   +   143 wr)
==15356== LLd misses:        172  (     89 rd   +    83 wr)
==15356== D1  miss rate:     0.5% (    0.3%     +  12.9%  )
==15356== LLd miss rate:     0.1% (    0.0%     +   7.5%  )
==15356== 
==15356== LL refs:         1,032  (    889 rd   +   143 wr)
==15356== LL misses:         452  (    369 rd   +    83 wr)
==15356== LL miss rate:      0.2% (    0.1%     +   7.5%  )
```

-

```
 % valgrind --tool=callgrind --I1=512,8,64 --D1=512,8,64
--L2=16384,8,64 ./ex
==15376== Callgrind, a call-graph generating cache profiler
==15376== Copyright (C) 2002-2012, and GNU GPL'd, by Josef Weidendorfer et al.
==15376== Using Valgrind-3.8.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==15376== Command: ./ex
==15376== 
--15376-- warning: L3 cache found, using its data for the LL simulation.
==15376== For interactive control, run 'callgrind_control -h'.
==15376== 
==15376== Events    : Ir Dr Dw I1mr D1mr D1mw ILmr DLmr DLmw
==15376== Collected : 111532 2777 102117 474 406 151 279 87 85
==15376== 
==15376== I   refs:      111,532
==15376== I1  misses:        474
==15376== LLi misses:        279
==15376== I1  miss rate:    0.42%
==15376== LLi miss rate:    0.25%
==15376== 
==15376== D   refs:      104,894  (2,777 rd + 102,117 wr)
==15376== D1  misses:        557  (  406 rd +     151 wr)
==15376== LLd misses:        172  (   87 rd +      85 wr)
==15376== D1  miss rate:     0.5% ( 14.6%   +     0.1%  )
==15376== LLd miss rate:     0.1% (  3.1%   +     0.0%  )
==15376== 
==15376== LL refs:         1,031  (  880 rd +     151 wr)
==15376== LL misses:         451  (  366 rd +      85 wr)
==15376== LL miss rate:      0.2% (  0.3%   +     0.0%  )
```

Could someone give me a reasonable explanation? Would I be correct to consider there are in fact ~100k reads and ~100k writes (i.e. 2 cache accesses for an addl)?

Answer (score 3):

[From cachegrind manual: 5.7.1. Cache Simulation Specifics](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cg-manual.html#cache-sim)

> - Instructions that modify a memory location (e.g. inc and dec) are
>     counted as doing just a read, i.e. a single data reference. This may
>     seem strange, but since the write can never cause a miss (the read
>     guarantees the block is in the cache) it's not very interesting.
>
>   Thus it measures not the number of times the data cache is accessed,
>     but the number of times a data cache miss could occur.

It would seem that callgrind's cache simulation logic is different from cachegrind.  I would think that callgrind should produce the same results as cachegrind, so maybe this is a bug?

Comment: That's exactly my thoughts. Probably a bug but it's surprising. Did they wrote a cache simulation twice?

Comment: From what I can see, it seems they implemented atleast part of the cache simulation twice.  I don't fully understand the native->VEX IR conversion and instrumentation logic.

Answer (score -1):

callgrind does not full cache simulation by default. see here: http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cl-manual.html#cl-manual.options.cachesimulation

To enable data read access you need to add --cache-sim=yes for callgrind.
Having said this, why even using callgrind on this code? There is not a single function call (which is what callgrind is for)

Comment: Adding cache-sim=yes doesn't change anything: specifying the cache sizes automatically activates the cache simulation.